# Indention of appCode for blocks

Tags: xcode, appcode

I really don't like how AppCode is indenting blocks like in the example below.

I would like to set up AppCode to indent blocks like Xcode does or even indent then even more so it easier to say where the method name ends and the block begins. How is this possible?

AppCode:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.f
                      delay:.2f
     usingSpringWithDamping:1.f
      initialSpringVelocity:-1.5f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
    self.buttonConstraint.constant = 0;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (finished) {
        if (completionBlock) {
            completionBlock();
        }
    }
}];
```

Xcode:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.f
                      delay:.2f
     usingSpringWithDamping:1.f
      initialSpringVelocity:-1.5f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     self.buttonConstraint.constant = 0;
                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if (finished) {
                         if (completionBlock) {
                             completionBlock();
                         }
                     }
                 }];
```

Comment: I think it is not possible yet http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-10190